# populate column in dataframe with a list using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to populate a dataframe using a for loop.
one of the column is a list.
this list is empty at the begining at each itteration an element is added or removed from it.

when I print my list at each iteration I am getting the right results, but when I print my dataframe, I am getting the same list on each row:

I you have a look to my code the list I am updatin is list_employe. The magic should happen in the 3 last rows but it did not.

Does anyone have an idea why the list is updated in one way and the dataframe record only the last update on all rows

```
list_employe = []
total_employe = 0
rows=[]



shiftday = example['SHIFT_DATE'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').unique().tolist()

for i in shiftday:
    shift_day = example[example['SHIFT_DATE'] == i]
    list_employe_shift = example[example['SHIFT_DATE']==i]['EMPLOYEE_CODE_POS_UPPER'].unique().tolist()
    new_employe = 0
    end_employe = 0
    
    for k in list_employe_shift:
        shift_days_emp = shift_day[shift_day['EMPLOYEE_CODE_POS_UPPER'] == k]
        days = shift_days_emp.iloc[0]['last_day']
        #print(days)
        if k in list_employe:
            if days>1:
                end_employe= end_employe+1
                total_employe = total_employe-1
                list_employe.remove(k)
        else:
            new_employe = new_employe+1
            total_employe = total_employe + 1
            list_employe.extend([k])
            
    day = i
    total_emp = total_employe
    new_emp = new_employe
    end_emp = end_employe
    rows.append([day, total_emp, new_emp, end_emp, list_employe])
    print(list_employe)
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=["day", "total_employe", "new_employe", "end_employe", "list_employe"])
```

Comment: The print  **list_employe** of the five first rows show this which is what I need :

[276, 281, 31, 263, 245, 15, 775, 267, 178, 274]
[276, 281, 31, 263, 245, 15, 775, 267, 178, 274, 212, 243, 229]
[276, 31, 263, 245, 15, 267, 178, 212, 243, 229, 295, 2013, 265, 288]
[276, 31, 245, 15, 178, 212, 243, 295, 2013, 265, 288, 289]

and my df  on column **list_employe** show the same list on each row:

[276, 281, 31, 263, 245, 15, 775, 267, 178, 274, 212, 229, 2013, 265, 289, 220, 173, 290, 285, 297, 293, 291, 298, 294, 299, 300, 304, 303, 305, 306, 308, 309, 307, 310, 311, 312, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the list `list_employe` is always the same object that you append to the list `rows`. What you need to do to solve the problem is at the 3rd line from the bottom : `rows.append([day, total_emp, new_emp, end_emp, list(list_employe)])` 
 Which create a new list at each itteration